# Mongo db mapping users to cities and longtitude latitude

Tags: mongodb

I was wondering what is the right schema for mapping users to cities.

Do I embed the information or create a reference.

My main usecase is to be able to identify all the users that are near a specific user. So I think embedding is right.

However yy problem with embedding the info, is what happens if I decide I want to change the name of a city, or add extra info for a city that will be updated for all users. How do I do that?

I have a MongoDB collection of users and want to be able to find all the users close to another another user. I guess for this I can use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution A**:

Position of user:

users:

```
{
    _id : 1,
    name : "John Doe",
    pos : [{longitude}, {latitude}],
    city : 1
}
```

cities:

```
{
    _id : 1,
    name : "New York",
    // ...
    pos : [{longitude}, {latitude}] // only if you need it
}
```

Find nearest users (first query), then find cities of nearest users (second query).

**Solution B:**

Position of city:

users:

```
{
    _id : 1,
    name : "John Doe",
    city : 1
}
```

cities:

```
{
    _id : 1,
    name : "New York",
    // ...
    pos : [{longitude}, {latitude}]
}
```

Find closest city (first query), then find all users in the closes city (second query).

**Embeding:**

It is common approach to embed some data you need very often with the main record. Let's say you put city name to user too. Yes, there is some data redundancy. Use this just if it really helps (application needs this data set very often).

In such case you would keep both collections. Then you can read all required data in single db hit. If you need change city name, you need to update city and all users from edited city. You will do it on application level and you need to be careful to keep data consistency.

users:

```
{
    _id : 1,
    name : "John Doe",
    pos : [{longitude}, {latitude}],
    city : {
        id : 1,
        name : "New York"
    }
}
```

cities:

```
{
    _id : 1,
    name : "New York",
    population : 10000000,
    flagFileName : "NewYorkFlag.jpg",
    pos : [{longitude}, {latitude}],
    // ...
}
```